# Read chars in Text area and produce desired output back in Text area, for Text Editor project

Tags: java, input, textarea, output

I am working on a personal project and want to create a text editor to write my code. I am wondering how could I read the last input from the user and if say it was an open curly brace {, then like netbean's my editor will supply the closing curly brace. My java experience is limited but have tried to read key board input and a few other options that did not work. I would really appreciate some help and guidance on the subject please?

Comment: Have a look at [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for the basics....personally, I'd find an already made implementation :P

Comment: Thank you, your links were very helpful :)